# VS2010 base web application and extended application and version control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, c#-4.0, version-control, projects-and-solutions

Currently I have one base webapplication, lets call it "Framework.Presentation".
This application contains all of the base items (default code and some default templates) of the web application.
For multiple customers, I want to extend this base application with client specific code and templates.
The base application is a subversion repository, and for each client we want a different subversion repository.

I had the following structure in mind:

```
ClientProject
  - Framework
    - Framework.Presentation
  - ClientProject.Presentation
```

The "ClientProject" is a repository on it's own, with an External to my Framework repository.
In my ClientProject.Presentation project, I'll link to the Framework.Presentation project.

This isn't a problem, however:

In the Framework.Presentation I have some templates in the App_Data folder, lets say:

```
App_Data
  - Templates
    - Default
      - All the files here
```

In my ClientProject.Presentation I could add the same, without the folder 'Default'. The application will look first directly in the `App_Data/Templates`, and after it in `App_Data/Templates/Default`.

Also the Framework.Presentation has an '/Admin' folder, where users should be able to do some admin stuff of the web application.

If I publish the ClientProject.Presentation, all the files fall in place. However, if I want to debug the application in VS2010, the files of the Framework.Presentation aren't copied to the root folder of the ClientProject.Presentation project, so I can't debug all the functions. Also the application cant find his default templates.

In which way can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe I can fix it with pre/post-build events and (x)copy?

Comment: Are the files in Framework.Presentation included in the ClientProject solution? In the past (on a much smaller scale) I have "imported" an external file into a different location in the folder structure, and have included a link to it within the solution. I can expand with an example if you think this might potentially be what you want.

Comment: The Framework.Presentation project, is included in my ClientProject solution, if this is what you mean

Comment: I'm not sure you want it to be though? You want the files included, but not the actual project?

Comment: The project is also included. However, they are in a different directory now (Framework/Framework.Presentation), for debugging some files (like Default.aspx, Global.asax, they will be the same for all client projects) needs to be in the root in the ClientProject.Presentation

Comment: Using that solution, have you set the `Copy to Output Directory` property on the files to `Copy always`?

Comment: Then the files are copied to the bin directory

Answer (score 0):

OK, a potential solution is...

Using your file structure, you add the project `ClientProject.Presentation` to the solution.

You *dont* add the `Framework.Presentation` project. Instead you add each file individually to your `ClientProject.Presentation` as a **link file**. (`Add` -> `Existing Item`, select the file, click the down arrow on the add button, and select `Add As Link`).

This will ensure that the files are still saved in the appropriate location in the file system, but the IDE will know where they live in the solution.

The only drawback is this will be fairly tedious, depending on the size of your `Framework.Presentation` project.

Comment: When I add some new files to Framework.Presentation, I have to update all the different client projects to add the files too. I don't think this is a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly create a `Framework.Presentation` DLL that is referenced by your `ClientProject.Presentation` project. You would need to configure your Framework files as embedded resources. I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure how well it would work.

Comment: I will try this later. However, I don't think it will find the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pre-build event as you suggested to copy all the files from the `Framework.Presentation` folders to the `ClientProject.Presentation`. However I suspect that this might get messy. For example:

- How do you handle filename clashes?
- Would you need to exclude the `Framework.Presentation` files in the `ClientProject.Presentation` folder so you don't accidentally commit them to subversion.
- Would you also need to automatically update the `ClientProject.Presentation` project to reference these files? If not, how will they get built and debugged? If so, how do you handle the project reload?
- How would you handle the extra files for clean builds, build server integration, deployment packages, etc.

Comment: I thought about this solution also. Then I should make a batch file in Framework.Presentation which copies the files I need, but does not overwrite them. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper solution. In this you should have all of your projects. Add a post build step to do all of the copying ect. You're not going to find a simple or clean solution to your problem. If you're not well acquainted with MSBuild you will be soon. It is certainly capable of doing everything you want, it's just going to be tedious.

Comment: Thats ok for CI, but not for local development. And I believe you still still run into problems similar to those already mentioned? (filename collisions, project file updates, etc)

Comment: @Mightymuke Alright I'm editing with a suggestion for how to structure your project to build locally although it's not going to be simple. You're don't anticipate an inordinate amount (like more than 30) of ClientProjects do you?

Comment: @Mightymuke edited with my suggestion for local builds. Good luck with it.

Comment: If I add a build step for copying, the files won't be deleted on a 'Clean', this is a problem.. Because on copy, I do not want to overwrite existing files (client project may add a different page than the framework), but after an update in the framework, this new file should be used

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned, this is one of the situations where it will start to get messy. Maybe you could work around it by adding a prefix to the  framework file names (for example).